In GCC, inside a lambda, I can get constexpr variable from a non-constexpr template lambda, but not in Visual C++
This code compiles fine in gcc, but fail in Visual C++.
MCVE = https://godbolt.org/z/K7d5PEs65
int main(){
      int localVariable=0; //some local variable
      auto lamb=[&]<int s>() {
          if constexpr(s==5){localVariable=7;}
          ///^ may modify some local variables
          return 8;
      };
      constexpr int gOk=lamb.operator()<2>();
      [&]<int s2>() {
          ///vvv can edit only here
          constexpr int gFail=lamb.operator()<s2>();
          ///^^^ can edit only here
      }.operator()<2>();
}


Error C2131   expression did not evaluate to a constant

I need gFail to be a constexpr variable, while lamb sometimes create run-time side effect, depending on the value of template variable s.
Please give reference and workaround for Visual C++ case.
Edit: By the way, the reason that I mix between constexpr and non-constexpr inside the same lamb is to make calling convenient.  By design, in user mind, he must know in advance that the instance of function lamb is constexpr or not.

Can even be simplified Demo

Don't even need to call the second lambda. And capturing lamb by value doesn't help any. The error says "failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime", but I don't see which variable it could possibly be talking about. Looks like a bug to me.

Ah. Making lamb itself constexpr helps with the simplified example; but not the original: "failure was caused by taking the address of an object that does not have static storage duration". So looks like there's no way to win here: if lamb is constexp, it can't modify a local variable, and if it's not constexpr, it can't be used to initialize a constexpr variable.

I had to fight with the same "read of a variable outside its lifetime" issue in MSVC. I think it is a bug/deficiency of the compiler.

I believe the problem you experience it is a bug/deficiency of MSVC, but I would let language lawyers provide the exact reasons (or refutation of my statement).
Typically what I do in these situations is to pack the constexpr value inside an integral constant. This is something MSVC can chew:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
int main(){
      int localVariable=0; //some local variable
      auto lamb=[&]<int s>() {
          if constexpr(s==5){localVariable=7;}
          return std::integral_constant<int, 8>{};
      };
      constexpr int gOk=lamb.operator()<2>().value;
      [&]<int s2>() {
          auto tmp = lamb.operator()<s2>();
          constexpr int gFail=tmp; //tmp implicitly casted from integral_constant to int.
      }.operator()<2>();
}

tmp needs to be explicitly spelled out for MSVC. If you assign directly to gFail you get the same "not evaluate to a constant".
Unfortunately this does not follow your "can edit only here" guide.

Update: I am concerned that what you do won't actually work in any compiler. If you try using 5 as a template argument, you do actually get an error in all three compilers:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
int main(){
      int localVariable=0; //some local variable
      auto lamb=[&]<int s>() {
          if constexpr(s==5){localVariable=7;} //error
          ///^ may modify some local variables
          return 8;
      };
      constexpr int gOk=lamb.operator()<5>();
      std::cout << localVariable;
}

gcc gives:
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:12:43:   in 'constexpr' expansion of 'lamb.main()::<lambda()>()'
<source>:8:43: error: the value of 'lamb' is not usable in a constant expression
    8 |           if constexpr(s==5){localVariable=7;}
      |                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
<source>:7:12: note: 'lamb' was not declared 'constexpr'
    7 |       auto lamb=[&]<int s>() {
      |            ^~~~
Compiler returned: 1


Thanks for the first part.  It is an interesting discovery.  It can be useful or very useful. .......   The second part ::  By my design, the second part with <5> (thus modify variable at runtime) should be fail. It is ok.

How did you know this correct answer? It looks so hard to guess.

As I said in other comment, I was fighting MSVC on something similar with the same error message.
